# A question on convergence of derivative of power series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

This is a question from Fourier Analysis with Applications by Folland. First we write Fourier series for $$e^{\theta}=\sum c_ne^{in\theta}$$ We differentiate this series term by term to obtain $$e^{\theta}=\sum inc_ne^{in\theta}$$ But by uniqueness of Fourier series we have $c_n=ic_n$ which implies that $c_n=0$. This is clearly wrong but where is the fallacy. If someone can tell what is going wrong it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Why one can differentiate the above series term by term ?

Comment: @Inquisitive I understand that differentiating term by term causes fallacy but I do not understand why we cannot differentiate since the fourier series converges uniformly in $(-\pi,\pi)$

Comment: The Fourier series of $f$ is $\frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi} \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{1-in} e^{in\theta};$

Comment: @Inquisitive Can you please explain it a bit more I could not understand your comment

Comment: Suppose $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}c_{n} e^{in\theta}$ is the Fourier series of $f.$  Does it mean that $f(\theta)= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} c_{n} e^{in \theta}; \theta \in (-\pi, \pi)$ ?

Comment: @Inquisitive But here the function looks very smooth so isn't the fourier series supposed to converge?

Comment: I found your question interesting and finally I posed [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030941/for-f-theta-e-theta-is-it-true-that-hatfn1-in-0-for-all-n-in); (right now its not completely clear to me);