# For $f(\theta)= e^{\theta}$. Is it true that $\hat{f}(n)(1-in)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z.$?

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fake-proofs

(This is motivated from the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021333/a-question-on-convergence-of-derivative-of-power-series?noredirect=1#comment2101312_1021333))

Fact: If $f \in C^1(\mathbb{T})$, then the Fourier coefficients $\widehat{f'}(n)$ of the derivative $f′$ can be expressed in terms of the Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(n)$ of the function $f$, via the formula $\widehat{f'}(n) = in \hat{f}(n)$

Take $f(\theta)=e^{\theta}, \theta \in (-\pi, \pi).$ Note that $f'(\theta)=f(\theta)$ and  $f\in C^{1}(\mathbb T);$ by above fact $\hat{f}(n)=in \hat{f}(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z.$ and so $\hat{f}(n)(1-in)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z.$  Since $\mathbb C$ is an integral domain, $\hat{f}(n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z.$ But if this the case then $f$ is identically zero function which certainly not true!!!!

**So my Question is**: Where is the fallacy in the above argument ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

$f(\theta)=e^\theta$ is not $C^1$, not even continuous, on $\mathbb{T}$. It is continuous on $[\,0,2\,\pi\,]$, but $f(0)\ne f(2\,\pi)$.